# How do improve the bounce rate of software download pages where visitors just download and leave?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, bounce-rate

i have an e-commerce site for security cameras. 
i have articles and software for download too.

the most visited pages are software download pages. users find the page on google results, open the software page, download and leave.

this makes my site's bounce rate 73%.

what solution is there too improve bounce rate?
what technik is there to prevent software pages from effect badly on bounce rate of the hole website.

my site: https://www.farafan-market.ir/

Comment: Consider making an english version of your site to attract more people, and for each software download, add a good description of what the software is supposed to do and make sure the software you make avaliable is free of viruses.

Comment: Is it simply the metric you want to reduce, to make your stats look better? Or do you literally want to reduce the bounce rate when users hit a download page?

Comment: You tagged this as "SEO", but bounce rate has very little to do with SEO.   Google has said they don't use bounce rate as measured by Google Analytics as a ranking factor.   Instead they may use "bounce back rate" which is the rate at which users use the back button.   It doesn't sound like your users are going back to Google unhappy.  It sounds like they are finding exactly what they want on your site.  As long as you are satisfying your visitors you won't have any ranking problems.   It doesn't matter if you satisfy the users in 10 page views or in just one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's obvious that this page is very important for users, but if users don't register another page view on your site, it doesn't matter what they do on this page - it will result in a bounce, as you are experiencing.

1. Set-up conversion tracking within Google Analytics. Your conversion action or goal within google analytics could be a "download" see image below:

[image]

You can record the download as a virtual pageview or as an event in Analytics, then set that virtual pageview/event as your goal.

Here's a nice little article on the difference between the two and how to implement each from [Search Engine Land](https://searchengineland.com/virtual-pageviews-or-event-tracking-%E2%80%93-which-is-right-for-you-125615).

Comment: main goal of may site is selling a product. can i set downloads as an event not a goal? do u recommend virtual pageview or event in this case?